# Google API Python - KeyError: _module

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to use the quickstart.py ( https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python ) as per Google's Gmail API using oauth2. I am getting the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "quickstart.py", line 54, in main
    credentials = get_credentials()
  File "quickstart.py", line 37, in get_credentials
    credentials = store.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 407, in get
        return self.locked_get()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/file.py", line 54, in locked_get
        credentials = client.Credentials.new_from_json(content)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 302, in new_from_json
        module_name = data['_module']
    KeyError: '_module'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I have figured it out. The `client_secret.json` file which is downloaded from Google API console should be placed in the same directory as the python `quickstart.py` file and not inside `~/.credentials` directory. This fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was that I thought `storage.json` is supposed to be some file containing something, but it is supposed to be just a file name where the Python script can save data. So as soon as I gave it a path to a non-existing file, it worked.

Comment: Such a helpful answer. You explained precisely how the mechanism works. This is very useful when there is difficult documentation around the web.